# Determining if a user has two pairs in a poker hand using regex

Tags: regex

Given a five-card poker hand with cards `A23456789TJQK`, I can use a regex to find if there is a single pair in a hand by doing:

```
.*(.).*\1
```

https://regex101.com/r/1OMHnJ/1

This works by referencing a captured group or card -- if it repeats, the regex is successful, and if not, it isn't.

However, it becomes a bit more difficult when there are two pairs. I first started my approach by doing a similar capture group and then checking if `\2` exists, but this doesn't work well if there are 3- or 4-of a kind -- it can sometimes mistake this for a 2-pair.

What would be a good regex for an unordered hand to see if it contains two (different) pairs?

Comment: You're going to get regexes banned from casinos.

Comment: Perhaps you could first sort them and then use `(.)\1+` to get the consecutive cards https://regex101.com/r/CPeVku/1

Comment: `(?=.*?(.).*\1)(?=.*?(?!\1)(.).*?\2)` identifies two-pairs. Same as `(.)(?=.*?\1).*?(?!\1)(.).*?\2`

Comment: @ctwheels cool, put it in an answer when you're ready!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple backreferences to accomplish this.

See it in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/1OMHnJ/5)

```
^(?!.*?(.)(?:.*?\1){2})(?=.*?(.).*?\2)(?=.*?(?!\2)(.).*?\3).*
```

It works as follows:

- `^` assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!.*?(.)(?:.*?\1){2})` negative lookahead ensuring a triple match isn't there
- `(?=.*?(.).*?\2)` positive lookahead ensuring a pair of characters exists in the string
- `(?=.*?(?!\2)(.).*?\3)` positive lookahead ensuring a pair of characters exists in the string that are different from the first pair (from the previous positive lookahead)
- `.*` match the string

Comment: thanks again for this great answer. One question on this, why do you use lazy `*`s on the above? What would happen if those were greedy instead?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 I just realized my logic was sort of flawed. I updated it to include a fix for a character appearing more than twice.

Comment: thanks for the update. This one was much, much more complex than I thought it would be with all the lookaheads...

Comment: and on a different note: how did you become so good with regular expressions? I feel like it's quite a bit different than something like SQL or a programming language, and much of 'getting it to work' is employing various tricks and being creative.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 honestly, don't know. I did frequent string manipulations and copy/pasted the odd regex here and there, but never really put much thought into it. One day I guess I needed something more complex, looked into it further and got lost. Haven't found my way out since. There's a lot of resources out there, but I find StackOverflow (and teaching others) has helped me become more fluent in regex. Also, [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/) is like one of the best in the biz, so check [tag:regex] tag and look for his name everyone (comments, answers, etc.) - he's awesome.

Comment: great, thank you! I've started putting together combinations of the questions to see how far the boundaries can be pushed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58845139/using-regex-to-calculate-poker-hands-part-1